# Vue - Como aplicar uma diretiva 'v-mask' dinamico, com dados e sem dados?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mask

Estou utilizando a directiva v-mask, mas o dados do componente são dinâmicos, então em certos momentos utilizo o componente com mascara e em outros momentos sem mascara, mas na directiva v-mask, se utilizar ela vazia somente, v-mask="" retorna erro, preciso utilizar no html do componente quando tiver mascara aplicar o v-mask e quando não tiver desabilitar o v-mask

```
<v-text-field
    :rules="rules"
    :name="schema.model"
    :id="schema.model"
    v-bind="schema.attributesTextField"
    v-model="value"
    :ref="schema.model"
    @blur="onBlur"
    @click:clear="clear()"
    @change="onChange"
    @focus="onFocus"
    @input="onInput"
    v-mask="getMask"
  >
    <template v-slot:label>
      {{schema.attributesTextField.label}}
      <span
        v-if="schema.rules.includes('required')"
        class="red--text"
      >*</span>
    </template>
</v-text-field>

import { mask } from 'vue-the-mask';

directives: {
    mask
  }

getMask() {
      return this.schema.attributesTextField.mask || 'XX';
    }
```

Comment: Como são esses dados dinâmicos, onde estão?

Comment: as configurações para usar esse componente são dinâmicas, hoje uso o formulário baseado em schema usando o vue-form-generator, e uso esse componente para todos os tipos de input, como por exemplo, type text, tel, number. a ideia é adicionar essa directiva v-mask no componente só quando vier um parâmetro do serviço.

Comment: Tentou colocar **`return this.schema.attributesTextField.mask || false;`** ao invés de **`return this.schema.attributesTextField.mask || 'XX';`** ?

Comment: Sim tentei sim, não funciona

Comment: Então, perguntei sobre como estão vindo os dados, pq da para fazer dois elementos v-text-field um com o mask e o outro sem, e aí fazer um v-if conforme os dados mostra um elemento ou o outro.

Comment: Entendi, teste esse jeito, mas queria saber se tem outra forma, para não ficar repetindo o html por causa de uma directiva

Answer (score -1):

Olá, andei pesquisando sobre e a única forma que deu certo realmente foi utilizando as diretivas `insira o código aqui`v-if/v-else e "duplicando" o seu componente.

A diretiva `v-mask` não aceita `false`, `null`, `undefined` ou "", portanto só pode ser informada quando existir de fato.

Não está de acordo com as melhores práticas mas se você estiver componentizando corretamente seu projeto não deve impactar tanto na manutenção do código.